# How to set Docker ENTRYPOINT To NPM?

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile

I have a Node.js project that is using npm scripts. An excerpt from `package.json` :

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build-all": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --progress --config ./webpack/client.config.js && ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --progress --config ./webpack/server.config.js",
    "web": "python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8888",
    "server" : "./node_modules/.bin/electron-spawn ./dist/server.js"
  },
```

I'm creating a `Dockerfile` for this project. I was hoping to use npm as the ENTRYPOINT for the image. In the Dockerfile I have:

`ENTRYPOINT ['/usr/local/bin/npm' 'run']`

when I try to start a hcontainer form the image it says it cannot find npm

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/home/vagrant# docker run my_image web
web: 1: web: [/usr/local/bin/npm: not found
```

if I start a shell in the image it looks like the npm executable is at that path

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/home/vagrant# docker run -i -t --entrypoint /bin/bash my_image
root@5e7362a64412:/# ls /usr/local/bin/npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

Comment: Although, this is not a good idea as `npm` will not pass signals to child processes in containerised setting, more info e.g. in [this summary](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices/blob/master/sections/docker/bootstrap-using-node.md)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue seems to be due to the single quotes in the ENTRYPOINT. Could you check if using the double quotes the issue solves?

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/npm", "run"]
```

According to the [Docker guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), there are only two forms to write the ENTRYPOINT:

1. **exec form** (preferred): `ENTRYPOINT ["executable", "param1", "param2"]`
2. **shell form**: `ENTRYPOINT command param1 param2`